# Dynamically created volumes from Kubernetes not being auto-deleted on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-container-service

I have a questions about kubernetes and the default reclaim behavior of dynamically provisioned volumes. The reclaim policy is "delete" for dynamically created volumes in Azure, but after the persistent volume claim and persistent volume have been deleted using kubectl, the page blob on the vhd still exists and is not going away.

This is an issue because every time I restart the cluster, I get an new 1 Gib page blob I now have to pay for, and the old one, which is unused, does not go way. They show up as unleased in the portal and I am able to manually delete them in the storage account. However, will not delete themselves. According to "kubectl get pv" and "kubectl get pvc," they do not exist.

According to all the documentation I can find, they should go away upon deletion using "kubectl":

- http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/10/dynamic-provisioning-and-storage-in-kubernetes.html
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reclaiming

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I have found that this issue appears only when you delete the persistent volume before you delete the persistent volume claim.I know that is not intended behavior but it should be fixed or throw an error.

Comment: why not raise a bug or item on feedback? or a support ticket. how are we supposed to help you?

Comment: I did. I posted on microsoft developer network forum to get help and they pointed me here. Here is their reply:

`Support for Azure Container Services has moved to a new location:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-container-service


Proposed as answer by Monika chaudharyMicrosoft contingent staff, Moderator`

Comment: that's not a support ticket. I don't people here would be able to help you (unless somebody from ACS team stumbles upon this)